# Javascript convert comma seperated string of words to key value objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to convert a list of email to a key value object within an array. I start with `"email@mail.com,mike@example.com,john@gmail.com"` and I want to end up with

```json
[
   {"to": "email@mail.com"},
   {"to": "mike@example.com"},
   {"to": "john@gmail.com"}
]
```

Here's what I've tried

```js
var req = {
  query: {
    personalize:
      "email@mail.com,mike@example.com,john@gmail.com"
  }
};
var emailList = req.query.personalize;
var emailArr = emailList.split(",");
var emailObj = Object.assign({}, emailArr);
console.log(emailObj);
```

Here's what I ended up with

```bash
"0": "email@mail.com"
"1": "mike@example.com"
"2": "john@gmail.com"
```

After this I tried this one

```js
var req = {
  query: {
    personalize:
      "email@mail.com,mike@example.com,john@gmail.com"
  }
};
var emailList = req.query.personalize;
var arr = emailList.split(",");
const res = arr.reduce((acc,curr)=> (acc[curr]='to',acc),{});
console.log(res)
```

This got me close, but backwards for what I wanted. Yielding a result like

```bash
"email@mail.com": "to"
...
```

Comment: `emailList.split(",").map(to => ({to}))`

Comment: `"email@mail.com,mike@example.com,john@gmail.com".split(',').map(to => ({to}))`

Comment: Yes this is the solution I was missing! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As Ivar and Amir pointed out in the comments, this solution works.

```js
function mockTest() {
var req = {
  query: {
    personalize:
 "email@mail.com,john@gmail.com,me@example.com"
  }
};
var emailList = req.query.personalize;
console.log(createToList(emailList))
}

mockTest();

function createToList(emailString) {
  return emailString.split(",").map(to => ({to}));
}
```